# Проблема ООП в Python

Tags: python, ооп

Создал класс General_db где хочу что бы с функция search_id() могла использоваться в внутри класса в другой функции db_closes() но у меня выходит ошибка.

```
import psycopg2
from config.db import *

class General_db:
    def search_id():
        try:
            connection = psycopg2.connect(
                host=host,
                user=user,
                password=password,
                database=db_name
            )
            connection.autocommit = True
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                    """
                    SELECT vendor_id FROM trigger_table 
                    ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
                    """
                )
                return list(cursor.fetchone())[0]
        finally:
            if connection:
                connection.close()
                
    def db_closes(self):
        try:
            connection = psycopg2.connect(
                host=host,
                user=user,
                password=password,
                database=db_name
            )
            connection.autocommit = True

            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                    f"""
                        SELECT closes FROM traidings WHERE id={self.search_id}
                    """
                )
                return list(cursor.fetchone())[0]
        finally:
            if connection:
                connection.close()
```

При вызове нашего класса и обращаясь к closes_db() выходит ошибка, вот код:

```
from db.db_class import General_db


print(General_db.db_closes())
```

Вот такую ошибку выдает:

```
    print(General_db.db_closes())
TypeError: General_db.db_closes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: По пробуйте `General_db.db_closes(self)`

Comment: Выдает ошибку:  NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Убрать в `db_closes` self везде, а вызов функции search_id заменить на `General_db.search_id` или тоже самое но с круглыми скобками

Comment: да работает с круглыми скобками:  General_db.search_id()

Comment: Да, вам `self` не нужен, вы экземпляры класса не используете

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1468792/516861  помогите решить